# call php class functions through jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a dropdown which i want to fill through jquery. Problem that i am facing is that i want to call a class function directly from jquery. eg
My class_function PHP class contains get_locations function. how can i call this get_locations function using jquery .post method without introducing a third page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I usually do that is to have an if statement at the top of the php page checking for a special mode.

jquery

```
$.get(
   'page.php?mode=ajaxGetLocations&someVar=' + $('#someVar').val(),
   function(data) { $('#myDropDown').html(data); }
);
```

PHP - near the top of the code

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['ajaxGetLocations'])
{
    $someVar = $_REQUEST['someVar'];
    // Get your data here

    // Output your select box here
    ?>
    <select>
    ...
    </select>
    <?php
    exit; // You don't want to keep processing the page
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have your PHP page upgraded with

```
if (isset($_GET['get_locations'])) {
    echo $this->get_locations();
    return;
}
```

and call it from jQuery with

```
$.ajax({
//..
data: "get_locations=1",
//...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because jQuery and PHP run in entirely different environments - PHP on the server, jQuery on the client. jQuery runs after PHP is done.

You want to look into [jQuery's Ajax functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) to find out how to call a PHP script from Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is used to make an HTTP request from the browser, using JavaScript, without leaving the page.
so you cant call a class function directly... but you can handle it by allowing the constructor to call this function depending on the parameters you have passed